# Jquery call on edit button click in mvc grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is Grid column

```
 grid1.Column("", header: "Edit", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", "BootStrap", new { id = item.empId }, new { target = "_blank" })</text>)
```

I want to write jquery function to open below div if I click on above edit button

```
<div id="editView">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/BootStrap/EditEmployee.cshtml",new EmployeeModel.Employee2())
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grid1.Column("", header: "Edit", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", "BootStrap", new { id = item.empId }, new { target = "_blank", id = "myBtn" })</text>)
```

### JS:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#editView").show() //or open in dialog, or I don't know.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
grid1.Column("", header: "Edit", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", "BootStrap", new { id = item.empId,@onClick="EditEmployee()" }, new { target = "_blank" })</text>)
```

**Jquery function**

```
function EditEmployee()
  {
   $("#editView").show();
  }
```